# Magento 1 right count of products

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have a problem with magento 1.9. It is about quantity of products, which user adds to his basket.

First, user adds one item of some product.
It's ok on page test page and on right top basket information - everywhere you can see 1 item with right price.

But then problem starts. If only user adds some odd amount of product, 10000 for example, I see this.
I have message, that there is no such big quantity, but price counted and quantity is updated.
Please, give me some advice how to fix it.

Comment: is it allowing you to checkout?, generally it adds the quantity and update the price as well but it won't allow you to checkout.

Comment: Piyush, No, there is no button "Order"

Comment: Max, then there doesn't seems to be any issue

Comment: Piyush, technically you're right, but manager wants to limit the amount of goods somewhow. 

For example, it's quite clear, that we don't have 100000 items of some product. So we need to limit also the possibility to book this 100000 for user. 

As I understand, If we see someone books a lot of items of one product - stop count, null amount of goodss and give a message, that there is no such amount.

Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

you may want to create a module to observe event `sales_quote_item_qty_set_after`

**etc/config.xml**

```
<events>
    <sales_quote_item_qty_set_after>
        <observers>
            <modulename>
                <class>modulename/observer</class>
                <method>salesQuoteItemQtySetAfter</method>
            </modulename>
        </observers>
    </sales_quote_item_qty_set_after>
```

**Model/Observer.php**

```
/**
 * Disallow purchasing more items then currently in stock
 * 
 * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 */
public function salesQuoteItemQtySetAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $item = $observer->getItem();
    $order_qty = $item->getQty();
    $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($item->getProduct());

    if($order_qty > (int)$stock->getQty()) {
        $item->setData('qty', (int)$stock->getQty());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try to implement your code.

Comment: sure thing. don't forget to accept and upvote if it helped

Comment: And if I want to add a comment to user, that 'there is not enough cuantity' - should I add some function to observer? In the place where if is located?

Comment: Done partly. You should add:
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError("Your message here.");

When user is in cart you have only this mesage, but when he is in the shop - message is doubled. How to show message only if user is in cart?

Comment: what do you mean by doubled? Session messages usually show up only once. If the message is duplicated in the same view. then you should check if something invokes the event for a second time